# Auto Route Issue in nested navigation back method

Tags: flutter, navigation, auto-route

> I shared the solution below!

I am using auto_route package, in nested navigation I get error which says:

`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'TabsRouter' has no instance getter 'identifier'. E/flutter ( 5578): Receiver: Instance of 'TabsRouter'`

```
@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: "View,Route")
    class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
      @override
      List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
            AutoRoute(
              page: HomeRoute.page,
              path: "/home",
              initial: true,
              children: [
                AutoRoute(page: UserRoute.page, path: "user", initial: true),
                AutoRoute(page: SettingsRoute.page, path: "settings"),
              ],
            ),
            AutoRoute(
              page: UserDetailRoute.page,
            ),
          ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`7.8.4 works fine.`
Make sure you omit the ^ in your pubspec otherwise on ugprade it will resolve to 7.8.5
auto_route: 7.8.4

The difference which causes the problem is:

- routing_controller.dart v7.8.4:

  ```
  void _removeTopRouterOf(Key? key) {
      for (final ctr in List.unmodifiable(_childControllers).reversed) {
          if (ctr.key == key) {
            _childControllers.remove(ctr);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
  ```
- routing_controller.dart v7.8.5:

  ```
  void _removeTopRouterOf(Key? key) {
      for (final ctr in List.unmodifiable(_childControllers).reversed) {
          if (ctr.identifier == key) {
            _childControllers.remove(ctr);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
  ```